# leaflet map shows up grey

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, leaflet

I'm starting leaflet.js with the [quickstart](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html) but my map shows as grey... is there something I'm missing?

script.js:

```
var leafletMap = L.map('leafletMap').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.title.cloudmade.com/' + API_KEY + '/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; [...]',
        maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(leafletMap);

// marker
var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(leafletMap);
```

style.css:

```
#leafletMap {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My title</title>

    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/bootstrap.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/leaflet.css'>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.ie.css" />
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id='leafletMap'></div>

<script src='js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js'></script>
<script src='js/libs/bootstrap.js'></script>
<script src='js/libs/leaflet-src.js'></script>
<script src='js/config.js'></script>
<script src='js/script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Gives me:

[image]

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You need to implement the next section of the Quick Start Guide: you've initialized the map, but haven't added any tile layers to it, hence gray. So read on to the section beginning with **Next we’ll add a tile layer to add to our map**.

Comment: Solution: it was a typo: `http://{s}.title.cloudmade.com/'` should be--> `http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/'`

Comment: +1 for helping the leaflet tutorial, which needs to put the first 'demo' after the tile layer code. Its placement not only alongside but above `var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);` gives the illusion that the map should be working at that point.

Comment: You can add an example code to do this in the answer: `L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?{foo}', {foo: 'bar', attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>'}).addTo(map);`

Answer (score 19):

try this when page load;

```
setTimeout(function () {
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
}, 1000);
```

Comment: this actually helped me a lot.
In most cases I believe it would be OK to omit the arbitrary delay, just putting it right after current thread execution.

Comment: That solved it for me.. only a small tile is loaded from the api making 90% of the map gray, when i resize the window leaflet calls the api asking for more tiles, so this "hack" makes leaflet complete itself. Thanks!!

Comment: Note the delay was necessary in my case. Works with a delay. Does not without it.

Answer (score 10):

Another thing to watch.

If you check the network tab and the map tiles are loading ok, yet the map still remains grey, it can be due to CSS contamination from your surrounding page.

In my case it was:

```
img {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Fixed by overriding with:

```
.my-leaflet-map-container img {
    max-height: none;
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks for the help really couldn't figure out why it was not working

Answer (score 2):

You must style your map-container to have a nonzero height. *In my case I linked to my CSS file too late*; at the bottom of my `<body>` tag.

So my map container; `<div id="map"></div>`, probably had a height of `0px` at the time it loaded.

This means the map and its tiles tried to load into `0px` height. I suspect this produces a small tile "buffer"; everything outside the buffer zone was grey.

To fix it, I referenced my CSS file in the `<head>`. Referencing the CSS file in `<head>` does both:

- a good practice
- allows the styles to apply before the map tried to load

**UPDATE**

Don't forget to link the [Leaflet CSS file](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/) (if you haven't already). Otherwise your tiles may appear "mismatched"/staggered.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
      integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
      crossorigin=""/>
```

Another solution is to modify the `style` attribute of your map-container directly in HTML (i.e. CSS inline in HTML). I personally prefer my CSS to exist in a separate CSS file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a tile layer, here example form Open Street Maps

```js
// initialize Leaflet
var map = L.map('map').setView({lon: 0, lat: 0}, 2);

// add the OpenStreetMap tiles
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 19,
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
#map {height: 280px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.css" />

<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For my ionic app this was resolved by setting `trackResize: false` in my map configuration. This was only happening on Android and called by a `setTransform` function in the Leaflet source code that's only called on Android.

`Leaflet.map('map', {
     trackResize: false
})`

Answer (score 1):

Did you set a value for API_KEY in your code?

When I first ran the quickstart I was also confused why my map was grey, but I just realised I'd forgotten to retrieve an API access code (in my case, it was for Mapbox's service.)

Your URL line references API_KEY but you don't seem to be declaring it.

Answer (score 0):

The notes by elMarquis are useful if you've a problem when embedding inside something else. In my case I was using Gravity Forms on Wordpress, and they have image styles that have a wide scope, and are also set to important.

I'm still chasing the ultimate fix, but this should get you started if you have discovered the same issue:

```
<style>
    #map { position: inherit; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0; width:100%; height:300px;}
    .gform_wrapper ul li.gfield.gfield_html .leaflet-container img { max-width: none!important;}
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

in same cases like in vuejs, you need put initialize map function inner setTimout:

```js
 mounted() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.map = L.map(this.$refs.map).setView([-12.256545945045046, -55.52556684608532], 4)
      L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors'
      }).addTo(this.map)
    }, 500)
  },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).